# jQuery simple function with callback

Tags: javascript

I'm trying writing down a function which will do something then bind a callback when finished, I would like to specify the callback when I init the js function...

```
function hello(arg1,arg2,callback){
    alert(arg1 + arg2);

   callback;
} 

hello('hello','world',function callback(){
    alert('hey 2);
});
```

sorry for banal question, I'm trying to understand how to pass a callback function to a function.

Answer (score 4):

you need to call that function like anything else:

```
function hello(arg1,arg2,callback){
    alert(arg1 + arg2);

   callback();
} 

hello('hello','world',function callback(){
   alert('hey 2);
});
```

Note that in JavaScript there are better ways to execute that callback, like [.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply) or [call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) but that is only required if you plan on using the this keyword inside callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

Inside of the function that you pass a function to, you have to invoke the passed function i.e.

```
function hello(arg1,arg2,callback){
  alert(arg1 + arg2);

  callback(); // invoke the function (this is just one way)
} 

hello('hello','world', function (){
  alert('hey 2');
});
```

You might go further and give the callback function a different context when calling it using [`Function.prototype.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply) or [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/call)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/wsNzL/

```
function A(a,b,func)
{
alert(a+b);
    func();
}

A(1,2,function(){alert("callback called");});
```